# How run stored procedure in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I want run a stored procedure from a controller in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, but always get an error 500.

I want to send 2 parameters and receive a list.

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[listaProductoPrecio]
    @Minimo int,
    @Maximo int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Productos 
    WHERE PrecioProducto BETWEEN @Minimo AND @Maximo
END
```

And this is the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/listaEntrePrecios")]
public IEnumerable<Producto> listaEntrePrecios(int minimo, int maximo)
{
    var parameters = new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@Minimo", minimo),
                new SqlParameter("@Maximo", maximo)
            };

    var lista = context.productos.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE listaProductoPrecio @Minimo @Maximo", parameters).ToList();

    return lista;
}
```

I do that to try and run a stored procedure in an API, help please

Comment: 500 usually indicates that something is not well configured. Can you post how you are connecting to that sql server?

Comment: `var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Conexion");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<appDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));`

Comment: I can do post put and get, but not store procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing a comma:

```
"EXECUTE listaProductoPrecio @Minimo @Maximo"
```

should be

```
"EXECUTE listaProductoPrecio @Minimo, @Maximo"
```

Comment: all my day just for a simple ", " , I WANT TO DIEEE

Comment: thanksss so muchh

Comment: I would add that when you get 500 - you **always** get something in server log, assuming that it is properly configured. That should be your first troubleshooting step *before* posting on Stack Overflow!